# Given the Rodrigues' formula for Legendre's polynomials, show that it satisfies the ODE.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

The Rodrigues Formula for Legendre's Polynomials is $P_{l}(x)=\frac{1}{2^{l}l!}\frac{d^{l}}{dx^{l}}(x^2-1)^l$.

I wrote $P_{l}(x)=\frac{1}{2^{l}l!}\frac{d^l}{dx^l}\sum_{k=0}^l(-1)^{k-l}\frac{l!}{k!(l-k)!}x^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^l\frac{(-1)^{k-l}}{2^l}\frac{(2k)!}{k!(l-k)!(2k-l)!}x^{2k-l}$ and put it into the ordinary Legendre's Equation :$\frac{d}{dx}[(1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}P_{l}(x)]+l(l+1)P_{l}(x)=0$.

I got $\frac{d}{dx}[(1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}P_{l}(x)]+l(l+1)P_{l}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^l\frac{(-1)^{k-l}}{2^l}\frac{(2k)!}{k!(l-k)!(2k-l-1)!}[(2k-l-1)x^{2k-l-2}+(2k-l+1)x^{2k-l}+\frac{l(l+1)}{2k-l}x^{2k-l}]$

But I can't see why it equals to zero.

Is there other way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Is your aim to get the ODE expression of Legendre's polynomials？

Comment: @RocHang Thanks for your comment. I expressed Legendre's polynomials by Rodrigues' formula and tried to show that it satisfies the ODE. After putting it into the ODE and doing some derivatives, I don't understand why the result is equal to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another approach that does not explicitly use integration.  Use $ D $ to stand for $ d/dx$.

First, apply Leibniz rule for the $n+2$ derivative of a product,

$$
 \begin{align} 
  D^{n+2}(x^2-1)^{n+1} &= (x^2-1) D^{n+2}(x^2-1)^n \\
  & \quad + \left( n+2 \atop 1 \right) 2x D^{n+1}(x^2-1)^n \\
  &\quad\quad  + 2 \left(n+2 \atop 2\right) D^n (x^2-1)^n \tag{1}
 \end{align}
$$

Second, evaluate the same expression, but take one derivative first

$$ 
 \begin{aligned}
  D^{n+2}(x^2-1)^{n+1} &= D^{n+1} \Big( D(x^2-1)^{n+1} \Big) \\
  &= D^{n+1} \Big( (n+1) (x^2-1)^n \cdot 2x \Big)
 \end{aligned}
 $$

And apply Leibniz again,
$$
 \begin{align}
  D^{n+2}(x^2-1)^{n+1} &= 2x(n+1) D^{n+1}(x^2-1)^n \\
  &\quad + 2(n+1)\left(n+1 \atop 1 \right) D^n(x^2-1)^n \tag{2}
 \end{align}
 $$

Now divide through by $2^n n!$, subtract (1) from (2)  and use Rodrigues's formula to obtain,
$$
 \begin{align}
  0 &= -(x^2-1) P''_n - 2 (n+2) x P'_n - (n+2)(n+1) P_n \\
               &\quad \quad + 2(n+1)x P'_n + 2(n+1)(n+1) P_n \\
   &= (1-x^2)P''_n -2x P'_n +n(n+1) P_n 
 \end{align}
 $$
which is exactly what we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The function
\begin{align*}
g_n(x)& :=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left\{\left(1-x^2\right)P_n^{'}(x)\right\}\\
& =\left(1-x^2\right)P_n^{''}(x)-2xP_n^{'}(x)\tag{1}
\end{align*}
is clearly a polynomial of degree $n$. Then
$$g_n(x)=\sum_{s=0}^n c_{n,s}P_s(x).\tag{2}$$
To find the $c_{n,s}$, we multiply by $P_s(x)$, integrate from $-1$ to $1$ and use the following formula
$$\int_{-1}^1\left\{P_n(x)\right\}^2\text{d}x=\frac{2}{2n+1}.$$
Two partial integrations can obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{2c_{n,s}}{2n+1}& =\int_{-1}^1 P_s(x)g_n(x)\text{d}x\\
& =\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x)g_s(x)\text{d}x.
\end{align*}
Since $P_n(x)$ is orthogonal to all polynomials of lower degree, we claim that $c_{n,s}=0(s<n)$.

Comparing coefficients of $x^n$ in (1) and (2) yields
$$c_{n,n}=-n(n+1).$$
Thus the desired differential equation is
$$\left(1-x^2\right)P_n^{''}(x)-2xP_n^{'}(x)+(n^2+n)P_n(x)=0.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know the ODE expression of the Legendre polynomials. Sorry that I didn't state my question well: If given the Rodrigues formula, show that it satisfies the ODE. I have difficulty in confirming that the Rodrigues formula satisfies the ODE after I substitute it into it. After some calculations , I don't understand why the result is equal to zero. Again thanks for your answer.